# Saving Excel workbook causes userform to incorrectly respond to TAB and KeyDown events (but saving in code environment doesn't!)

Tags: excel, events, tabs, key, userform

I am using Excel 2013 on Windows 10. I have a userform which has a number of text boxes and corresponding  handlers for KeyDown, Enter, Exit events.

After coding all this, it works as expected. The runtime responds to key presses correctly so that the user can use the function keys and TAB between controls.

If I make a change to the workbook itself (not the VBA code or userform, I'm talking about editing the cells in the worksheets) and then save it, the userform stops responding to the key presses, and the TAB key behaviour changes: it puts tab characters within the text box instead of moving focus to the next control (and yes, I have the TabKeyBehaviour properties set to false).

It's taken me ages to understand how to reproduce this as it seemed to occur randomly, but I've finally realised that, if I save the Workbook from within the VBA dev environment, it's fine but, if I save from the Excel workbook save button (or CTRL+S), or I call the Workbook.Save method in code, it causes this strange behaviour.

Oddly, I've found that taking focus from the userform and back again (by opening and closing another form) causes the behaviour to revert to normal - but that's another thing; my question is: why saving within the dev environment is okay but saving outside of the dev environment causes this weird behaviour? And, of course, is there a solution to this?

(I can't make the file read-only because the workbook contains configuration data that the user needs to be able to change.)

Comment: To be honest, I have no answer for your specific question, but I learned that the save command in the development environment not always really saves the complete code changes (and according to my observations no changes in the workbook itself). If you set a certain behavior in the code of your user form, I would guess that the Workbook save command resets them to default.

Comment: The only behaviour in the form that could (but shouldn't be) be changed by the Workbook Save command would be design-time settings such as TabKeyBehaviour but, when I check, that property has not been changed. regardless of this, I can't see how the KeyDown event handlers in my code would stop firing just because I've saved the workbook. Thanks for your response though.